# Задания на Phython

Tags: python, работа-с-текстом

Пожалуйста помогите решить я бы и сам попробовал но я только и знаю что чуть чуть С#. Даже примерного кода нет. Спасите у меня дедлайн полтора часа

1. Дан  текст.  Определить  процентное отношение  строчных  и  прописных  букв  к  общему  числу  символов  в нем.
2. Дана  строка,  содержащая  последовательность  латинских  слов, разделенных  пробелами.  Определить  букву,  встречающуюся  в словах чаще всех остальных. Если такая буква не одна, то вывести первую в алфавитном порядке.
3. Задана строка. Определить самый часто встречающийся символ и количество его повторений.

Comment: тут это не так работает..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Дан текст. Определить процентное отношение строчных и прописных букв к общему числу символов в нем.

- определить является ли символ буквой - `str.isalpha()`
- определить является ли буква строчной - `str.islower()`
- число символов - `len(text)`
- проверить все буквы в строке - `for буква in текст:`

> 2. Дана строка, содержащая последовательность латинских слов, разделенных пробелами. Определить букву, встречающуюся в словах чаще всех остальных. Если такая буква не одна, то вывести первую в алфавитном порядке.

- сколько раз буква встречается в строке - `строка.count(буква)`
- сортировка в алфавитном порядке - `sorted()`

> 3. Задана строка. Определить самый часто встречающийся символ и количество его повторений.

- аналогично пп.1, 2